# Full reptend prime generation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm pretty undereducated when it comes to mathematics but I'm working on that! At the moment, I am trying to generate full reptend prime numbers and I'm having some problems (I know they can be found over at OEIS but that's no fun).

I understand that they can be generated using the formula:

$$\frac{b^{p-1}-1}{p},$$

$b$ being base, which is 10, and $p$ being a prime number. I know the GCD of $p$ and $b$ must be $1$. But when I actually run through this I get a lot of numbers that aren't reciprocal (which is exactly what planet math says should happen) but then it goes on to vaguely reference how the sequence of the numbers comes from algebraic number theory and leaves it at that. What is the means by which full reptend primes are discovered?

Thanks! Sorry for such a basic question, I've had a devil of a time finding an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Having never seen to before but having done a quick look at the Wikipedia page, it seems that they're probably discovered by trial and error by checking if the base b is a primitive root mod p. You can do this by  calculating the order of b mod p, or more quickly by checking $b^{(p-1)/2} = -1 \mod p$. But this is a guess, it's obvious to me that the primitive root property is the correct property here. So in short, I bet they find them by brute force.